# Obj-C/Cocos2d memory issue, exc_bad_access when calling property

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, exc-bad-access

I'm working on a card game for iOS, and I've run into what I'm guessing is a memory management issue in Objective-C that I just can't figure out. I've read up multiple times on memory management and I think I'm doing everything right, but whenever I try to call out a property from my Card class, I get the game crashing.

The way it works is I have a NSMutableArray called deck that's a property of the CCLayer I'm using in Cocos2d. I allocate and init the deck in the init method of the layer, and then call a method that fills out the cards in the deck:

```
int i;
int j;
NSString *suit;

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

    switch (i) {
        case 0:
            suit = @"Hearts";
            break;
        case 1:
            suit = @"Clubs";
            break;
        case 2:
            suit = @"Spades";
            break;
        case 3:
            suit = @"Diamonds";
            break;
    }


    for (j=1; j < 15; j++) {

        Card *card = [[Card alloc] init];
        card.suit = suit;
        card.rank = j;
        [card makeName];
        [deck addObject:card];

    }

}
```

Over in the Card class I've got properties:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *suit;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic) int rank;
```

Which are each synthesized, and I've even tried allocating and initiating each of them in the Card's init method (which I don't think I need to do, but tried anyway).

The second I try to call a Card's property, however:

```
-(void) showCards: (NSMutableArray *) cards {

for (int i = 0; i < [cards count]; i++) {

    Card *card = [cards objectAtIndex:i];

    NSLog(@"%@",card.name);

}
```

}

No dice. Exc_bad_access. My guess is that the cards are somehow deallocating before I'm done using them, but I've done everything to keep them around that I can think of. Any thoughts? I'm guessing it's something simple that I've misunderstood, but I am out of ideas. Thanks!

Edit: Added by request:

Class declaration:

```
@interface Card : NSObject {

//NSString *suit;
//int rank;
//NSString *name;

}

property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *suit;
property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
property (nonatomic) int rank;'
```

init method (for now -- just added the alloc/init to see if it would work):

```
-(id) init {
self = [super init];
if (self) {

    suit = [NSString new];
    rank = 0;
    name = [NSString new];

}
return self;
}
```

Here's makeName:

```
-(void) makeName {

NSString *rankString;

switch (rank) {
case 1:
        rankString = @"One";
        break;
    case 2:
        rankString = @"Two";
        break;
    case 3:
        rankString = @"Three";
        break;
    case 4:
        rankString = @"Four";
        break;
    case 5:
        rankString = @"Five";
        break;
    case 6:
        rankString = @"Six";
        break;
    case 7:
        rankString = @"Seven";
        break;
    case 8:
        rankString = @"Eight";
        break;

    case 9:
        rankString = @"Nine";
        break;
    case 10:
        rankString = @"Ten";
        break;
    case 11:
        rankString = @"Jack";
        break;
    case 12:
        rankString = @"Queen";
        break;
    case 13:
        rankString = @"King";
        break;
    case 14:
        rankString = @"Ace";
        break;
}

NSString *cardName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ of %@", rankString, self.suit];

name = cardName;

}
```

Comment: Can you show your classe declaration and your init method?

Comment: You can understand if it is a deallocated instance by activating NSZombie: when you have a Exc_bad_access check in xcode if your Card is a zombie or not.

Comment: cards is just whatever array is passed to the "showCards" method. In the case I'm having trouble with, it's just the deck array.

Comment: Logging just card or cards both seem to work fine -- they output what look like standard ObjC object notation. But the app still breaks on the card.name log line.

Comment: You should always make object that have mutable subclasses (e.g. NSString) use the `copy` property type, not `retain`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're getting a bit mixed up between properties and instance variables.  Instance variables are what reference the objects, while properties are just a fancy way of assigning to them and getting them.

Where you have:

```
name = cardName;
```

What this is doing is assigning to the instance variable called `name`.  It is *not* assigning to the property - that is done with the dot syntax - `self.name = cardName`.  What will happen with the code as it stands is that you will lose the reference to whatever existing object you have in the instance variable - thus leaking memory - and the reference to the new object will be put in its place.  But if you look at where the new object is coming from:

```
NSString *cardName = [NSString stringWithFormat:...
```

...you will see that it is autoreleased.  So there's nothing retaining the object and it will be deallocated at some point in the future.  You'll still have a reference to the memory location, but it won't contain the object you want it to - this is a dangling pointer and the probable cause of your crash.

Now, if we switch to using the dot syntax:

```
self.name = cardName;
```

...what happens here is equivalent to `[self setName:cardName];`  This is a method that you generated with `@synthesize`.  This method will automatically release the object you are currently storing in the instance variable and retain the new object, because you declared the property to be `retain`.

Comment: This is excellent insight, and indeed, fixing the name assignment to dot syntax also fixed the crash. I will read up on ivars and properties -- you're right, I have some trouble understanding exactly what the difference is. Time to figure it out. Thanks very much for the help, appreciate it.